# How to load javascript in the JVM cross project

Tags: scala.js

I have run into some difficulties and was wondering if someone can help me.  I have the following Build.scala and I am trying to access the the compile javascript from the JVM project.

```
lazy val webProject = CrossProject(base = file("./main/web"), crossType = CrossType.Full, jvmId = "api-gateway", jsId = "web-js")
    .settings(
      name := "web",
      unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "shared" / "main" / "scala",
      libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.Client.sharedDeps.value)
    .jvmSettings(
      persistLauncher := true,
      persistLauncher in Test := false,
      libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.Client.jvmDeps.value)
    .jsSettings(libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.Client.jsDeps.value)

  lazy val webJS = webProject.js.enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

  lazy val webJVM = webProject.jvm
    .settings((resources in Compile) += (fastOptJS in(webJS, Compile)).value.data)
    .dependsOn(dominos)
```

The compile javascript is generated

```
[info] Fast optimizing /.../main/web/js/target/scala-2.11/web-fastopt.js
```

When I try to access the compile javascript by running get server, it can't be found.

```
object Main extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  val routes = pathEndOrSingleSlash(getFromResource("web-fastopt.js"))

  Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "localhost", 8080)
}
```

Isn't this line suppose to add the javascript the the JVM's resources folder when it runs?

```
(resources in Compile) += (fastOptJS in(webJS, Compile)).value.data
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this like doesn't work for me for some reason

```
(resources in Compile) += (fastOptJS in(webJS, Compile)).value.data
```

Instead I ended having to move the fastOptJS file

```
lazy val webJVM = webProject.jvm
    .settings(Seq(fastOptJS, fullOptJS, packageJSDependencies)
      .map(pkg ⇒ crossTarget in(webJS, Compile, pkg) := scalaJSOutput.value))
```

I also needed to add

```
getFromResourceDirectory("")
```

to the Akka Http routes.